# WordPress plugin suggestion for event registration

Tags: wordpress

Is there a good WordPress plugin for event registration (single event), that would have the following features?

- Ability for the user to send an initial request to sign up for the event
- Ability for an admin to approve / deny a request
- Denied requests simply receive an email stating they were denied.
- Accepted requests receive an email with another form where they enter more information and make an online payment (cash, bank transfer, paypal, etc.)
- I've found a couple of good plugins, but the "Accept/Deny" part where I have not found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

[EventEspresso](http://eventespresso.com/)

Seems to support this approval feature. I have no personal experience using it, but it seems to fit your requirements.

Personally I'm a big fan of [WPEvents](http://wp-events-plugin.com/), but I'm not sure whether it's suitable for your needs. But generally a really good event plugin. Definitely worthwhile to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The Events Calendar by Modern Tribe had a better beta than most plugins that were much older. Now that the plugin is over 5 years old (that's when I started using it) it's very solid and feature rich.

Free version here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/

There is a premium version too.